# Angularjs Google maps API drawing a shape

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I have an Ionic application wherein I have a Google map (the basic map without any added functionality). I want to:

1. Mark an area on this map as shown in the following image(these images are from somewhere else, I just found it online): At each click one point is added and after three points the first point is shown with a green tick to suggest that a polygon can be completed as shown in second figure.
   [image]
   [image]

How can I achieve this? I tried creating a marker for each click and then  using markers and then creating a polygon from those markers but polygon automatically gets completed on third point (and it really isn't similar behavior as I want). I would like a fresh solution. Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried sample given in [GoogleMap AngularJS Directive](https://github.com/ionicthemes/building-a-complete-mobile-app-with-ionic-framework/tree/master/www/lib/ngmap)? I hope that helps.

Comment: I am not how I can use it